# Exluding PyQT5 in cx_freeze to make library much smaller and exe startup much faster

Tags: python, pyqt5, cx-freeze

how to make a EXE library much smaller in size and the exe startup faster?. My library is actually 580 MB and the startup time from the exe is around 10 seconds! Here is my main.py. Its imports data from interface. (sub program)

```
import sys
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Tuple
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
import cv2
import os
from sys import path
import shutil
import xlsxwriter
from tkinter import Tk, PhotoImage, Canvas
from interface import *
from line_detection import *
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font
import os.path
```

The header of interface.py looks like this:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets 
import sys
import os.path
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl 
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, Font
from openpyxl import load_workbook
```

In Inteface.py i do something like this:

```
MyApp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
V = MyApp.desktop().screenGeometry()
h = V.height()
w = V.width()

class Ui_Form(object):
        def __init__(self):
                self.show_label = True
                self.show_groupbox = False

        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
                MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
                
                MainWindow.resize(w, h)
                self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)               

                self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
                self.image_label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
                self.image_label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, w, h))
                self.image_label1.setText("")
                self.image_label1.setObjectName("image_label1")        
                self.image_label1.setHidden(self.show_label)               
                self.image_label1.setDisabled(self.show_groupbox)
```

My cx_freeze (setup.py) looks like this. Its still including all packages and so on. How to make PyQT5 and other Packages much smaller when making a EXE

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

try:
    from cx_Freeze.hooks import get_qt_plugins_paths
except ImportError:
    include_files = []
else:
    # Inclusion of extra plugins (new in cx_Freeze 6.8b2)
    # cx_Freeze imports automatically the following plugins depending of the
    # use of some modules:
    # imageformats - QtGui
    # platforms - QtGui
    # mediaservice - QtMultimedia
    # printsupport - QtPrintSupport
    #
    # So, "platforms" is used here for demonstration purposes.
    include_files = get_qt_plugins_paths("PyQt5", "platforms")

# base="Win32GUI" should be used only for Windows GUI app
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

build_exe_options = {
    #[""]
    "excludes": ["PyQt5.QtBluetooth",
                 "PyQt5.QtNetwork",
                 "PyQt5.QtNfc",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebChannel",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebEngine",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebKit",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebKitWidgets",
                 "PyQt5.QtWebsockets",
                 "PyQt5.QtSql",
                 "PyQt5.QtScript"],

    "include_files": include_files,
}

bdist_mac_options = {
    "bundle_name": "TEST",
}

bdist_dmg_options = {
    "volume_label": "TEST",
}

executables = [Executable("main.py", base=base, target_name="TEST")]

setup(
    name="TEST",
    version="2.4",
    description="TEST",
    options={
        "build_exe": build_exe_options,
        "bdist_mac": bdist_mac_options,
        "bdist_dmg": bdist_dmg_options,
    },
    executables=executables,
)
```

Comment: Not use `from foo import *`, since that causes you to load all the components (and many you will not use) that the delay can cause. Better use `from foo import bar1, bar2`. Also remove `from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
`

Comment: it now looks like this: from PyQt5.Qt import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QTableWidget, QTableWidgetItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QImage
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
... but still 580MB library files...any idea?

Comment: 1. See the list of packages and eventually exclude them; 2. Your imports are **very** confusing, which is a problem for various reasons (including automated package detecting, but also code styling and readability, which should *never* be underestimated). For instance, you have 4 `from PyQt.QtGui import <ClassName>` but you also put `from PyQt5.QtGui import *` in between, which makes ***all*** other similar imports useless and pointless. Please use imports much more carefully.

Comment: i updated my code. I have a sub program (interface.py) which imports PtQt too. So maybe the problem is interace.py? Is the setup.py OK?